# How can I use an AlertService (mat snackbar for error messages) inside another service?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to subscribe an observable inside a service. However, I need to use `AlertService` for showing errors. A service inside another service (circular dependency?).

Here is AlertService

```js
@Injectable()
export class AlertService {
  private subject = new Subject<any>();
  private keepAfterNavigationChange = false;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    // clear alert message on route change
    router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        if (this.keepAfterNavigationChange) {
          // only keep for a single location change
          this.keepAfterNavigationChange = false;
        } else {
          // clear alert
          this.subject.next();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  success(message: string, keepAfterNavigationChange = false) {
    this.keepAfterNavigationChange = keepAfterNavigationChange;
    this.subject.next({ type: 'success', text: message });
  }

  error(message: string, keepAfterNavigationChange = false) {
    this.keepAfterNavigationChange = keepAfterNavigationChange;
    this.subject.next({ type: 'error', text: message });
  }

  getMessage(): Observable<any> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

AlertService becames a `Mat Snackbar` on `AlertComponent`. I'm rendering this snackbar on another components.

```js
export class AlertComponent implements OnInit {
  message: any;

  constructor(private alertService: AlertService, public snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // trigger Snackbar after AlertService is called
    this.alertService.getMessage().subscribe(message => {
      if (message != null) {
        // there is a message to show, so change snackbar style to match the message type
        if (message.type === 'error') {
          this.snackBar.open(message.text, undefined, { duration: 8000, verticalPosition: 'bottom', panelClass: ['snackbar-error'] });
        } else if (message.type === 'success') {
          this.snackBar.open(message.text, undefined, { duration: 8000, verticalPosition: 'bottom', panelClass: ['snackbar-success'] });
        } else {
          this.snackBar.open(message.text, undefined, { duration: 8000, verticalPosition: 'bottom' });
        }
      }
    });
  }

}
```

I'm able to subscribe inside components like this:

```js
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.emailService.sendEmail('example@gmail.com')
      .subscribe(code => {
          console.log(code);
          this.alertService.success('Thanks for your message!');
      }, error => {
        this.alertService.error('Error sending message.');
      }
    );
  }
      
}

@Injectable()
export class EmailService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    sendEmail(email: Email) {
        return this.http.post(BACKEND_URL + 'send', email);
    }
}
```

However im trying to subscribe inside service because `EmailService` will be used in more than one component. How can I achieve this behavior?

Comment: what is the problem using service inside a service? This is not a *circular dependency*

Comment: i tried to use AlertComponent inside EmailComponent but i got an circular dependency console alert

Comment: that means you have a circular dependency but this is not because of using service inside a service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service can be injected in other services

```
@Injectable()export class EmailService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private alertService: AlertService) { }

sendEmail(email: Email) {
    return this.http.post(BACKEND_URL + 'send', email).map( result => this.alertService.alert(result););


  }
}
```

It would have been circular if AlertService uses EmailService and EmailService uses AlertService

Answer (score 1):

The only drawback of this solution is that when you have multiple alerts, the one showing will be dismissed so that you won't have the time to read it. I modified slightly your code to allow multiple alerts.
Alertservice looks like this:

```
export class AlertService {
  
  private subject = new ReplaySubject<any>();

  private  showsubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(1);
  
  public alert =                
  zip(this.subject.asObservable(),this.showsubject.asObservable());

  success(message: string) {
    this.subject.next({ type: 'success', text: message });
  }

  error(message: string) {
    this.subject.next({ type: 'error', text: message });
  }

  shownext(){
    this.showsubject.next(1);
  }
}
```

and in AlertComponent we have:

```
    ngOnInit(): void {  
    
    this.alertService.alert.subscribe(([message,show]) => {
      if ( message&&message.text ) {
        // there is a message to show, so change snackbar style to match the message type
        if (message.type === 'error') {
         this.snackbarref  =  this.snackBar.open(message.text, 'Ok', { verticalPosition: 'top', panelClass: ['snackbar-error'] });
        } else if (message.type === 'success') {
          this.snackbarref= this.snackBar.open(message.text, undefined, { duration: 3000, verticalPosition: 'top', panelClass: ['snackbar-success'] });
        } else {
          this.snackbarref= this.snackBar.open(message.text, 'Ok', { duration: 3000, verticalPosition: 'top' });
        }   
        this.snackbarref.afterDismissed().subscribe(()=>this.alertService.shownext());
      }
      else this.alertService.shownext();
    });    
  }
```

Practiclly the zip operator is used to control when the next alert is shown.